# Finder error: Apple event handler failed

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write an applescript to pull a string from clipboard, parse it and create a folder if it satisfies a condition.

The string is always of the format "yyyymmdd.hhmmss.abc.xyz"

The code is pasted below:

```
set datevar to item 1 of my Splitstring(the clipboard, ".")
set yearvar to (datevar / 10000) as integer

on Splitstring(stringvar, del)
    set defaultdel to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to del
    set arrayvar to every text item of the stringvar
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to defaultdel
    return arrayvar
end Splitstring
.
.
.
.
.
.
if yearvar < 2002 then
    set tempvar to "/Volumes/My Passport/Cygnus-CME/Cycle-22-Min/Slow_CME/"
    set loc to POSIX path of tempvar
    tell application "Finder"
        make new folder at loc with properties {name:datevar} # ---- Error location
    end tell
end if
```

The command to create a new folder works fine if the path is something else. I have verified that the external HD is mounted and the permissions for my account are r&w.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a problem with the way I have set the path of the external HD?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Finder expects HFS paths (colon separated). An HFS path start always with a disk name and never with `Volumes`

```
set loc to "My Passport:Cygnus-CME:Cycle-22-Min:Slow_CME:"
tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at folder loc with properties {name:datevar}
end tell
```

or

```
set loc to POSIX file of tempvar
tell application "Finder"
   make new folder at loc with properties {name:datevar}
end tell
```